# How does Firebase.setAndroidContext(this) work and what does it do?

Tags: android, firebase

Could someone please explain how the following code snippet works?

```
public class FireBaseApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**`Context` is a class that can be used to do Android and app specific things.**

**If you would like to see methods of the `Context` class look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)**

Firebase needs access to those methods in the scope of your app, that's why you need to set it.

In your case you can call `Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);` with the `this` argument, because the `Application` class is a instance of the `Context` class.

Answer (score 1):

**It initializes the Firebase library with the Android Context**.

From Firebase documentation:

```
The Firebase library must be initialized once with an Android Context. This 
must happen before any Firebase reference is created or used.
```

A Context according to [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html):

```
It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as 
up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, 
broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.
```

I hope this explains well.

Comment: bro please  help me...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955696/how-multiple-tabs-carry-icon-with-text-in-a-fragment